# Implement clipboard 'Cut' operation with C1RichTextBox

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox, copy-paste, componentone

Due to an issue with large images in C1RichTextBox for Silverlight (5.0.20132.340), I want to implement the copy/cut/paste operations in my custom control. 
I am using the events `C1RichTextBox.ClipboardCopying` and `C1RichTextBox.ClipboardPasting` to do this. These are the only events (no ClipboardCutting event) and I don't see any overrideable methods to solve this differently.

Now when I do a CUT operation in the rich text box, the event `C1RichTextBox.ClipboardCopying` is fired too but I cannot decide whether it is Copy or Cut. There is a private member `C1RichTextBox._isCutOperation` which is used internally.

Any ideas how to decide whether Copy or Cut is being done?

Comment: Also see a more general question with a much nicer answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734350/c1richtextbox-with-custom-copy-paste-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also asked this question in the ComponentOne support forum and here's what they came up with:

> I would suggest you rather listen to KeyDown event for Ctrl+X and call
>   C1RichTextBox.ClipBoardCut method. This way you would be able to
>   handle the cur operation on C1RichTextBox.

Which lead me to the conclusion that you cannot use the event `ClipboardCopying` to implement custom Copy/Cut operation.

(**Edit**: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734350/c1richtextbox-with-custom-copy-paste-behavior) how to implement custom Copy/Cut/Paste)

After a few hours of tinkering I found the following solution (just in case someone else is going crazy over this):

```
public class C1RichTextBoxExt : C1RichTextBox
{
    public C1RichTextBoxExt( )
    {
        ClipboardMode = ClipboardMode.RichText;

        // Workaround for Copy/Paste issue in C1RichTextBox (5.0.20132.340) -> large images are not copied.
        ClipboardCopying += new EventHandler<ClipboardEventArgs>(RichTextBox_ClipboardCopying);
        ClipboardPasting += new EventHandler<ClipboardEventArgs>(RichTextBox_ClipboardPasting);
    }

    void RichTextBox_ClipboardCopying(object sender, ClipboardEventArgs e)
    {
        // store info in static fields since Silverlight clipboard cannot store html and text at the same time.
        _clipboardHtml = Selection.Html;
        _clipboardText = Selection.Text;

        // Another Workaround: cannot determine if Copy or Cut is going on ...
        // -> call the ClipboardCopy() method and let the C1RichTextBox do the cut/copy. Calling this method will
        //    however trigger the ClipboardCopying event again, so we most remove this method as event handler 
        //    temporarily.
        ClipboardCopying -= RichTextBox_ClipboardCopying;
        ClipboardCopy();
        ClipboardCopying += RichTextBox_ClipboardCopying;

        e.Handled = true; // operation is done, nothing more to do.
    }

    void RichTextBox_ClipboardPasting(object sender, ClipboardEventArgs e)
    {
        string current = Clipboard.GetText();
        // texts will not match exactly since C1 uses a different approach to copy text to the clipboard than
        // just using Selection.Text...

        if (TextsEqual(current, _clipboardText))
        {
            // text is the same -> assumption that html is still valid. Paste _clipboardHtml
            using (new DocumentHistoryGroup(DocumentHistory)) // enables undo/redo
            {
                // code from C1 library to paste html correctly ///////////////////
                C1Document c1Document = HtmlFilter.ConvertToDocument(_clipboardHtml);

                C1TextPointer c1TextPointer = c1Document.ContentStart;
                C1TextRange selection = Selection;
                C1TextPointer c1TextPointer2 = selection.Delete(!Selection.IsEmpty, false);

                List<Type> list = Enumerable.ToList<Type>(Enumerable.Select<C1TextElement, Type>(c1TextPointer2.Element.GetParents(), (C1TextElement elem) => elem.GetType()));
                list.Add(c1TextPointer2.Element.GetType());
                while (c1TextPointer.Symbol is StartTag && (c1TextPointer.Symbol as Tag).Element is C1Block && !((c1TextPointer.Symbol as Tag).Element is C1TableRowGroup) && list.Contains((c1TextPointer.Symbol as Tag).Element.GetType()))
                {
                    c1TextPointer = c1TextPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(1);
                }
                C1TextPointer c1TextPointer3 = c1Document.ContentEnd;
                while (c1TextPointer3.PreviousSymbol is EndTag)
                {
                    c1TextPointer3 = c1TextPointer3.GetPositionAtOffset(-1);
                }
                c1Document.FragmentRange = new C1TextRange(c1TextPointer, c1TextPointer3);
                selection.Fragment = c1Document;
                Selection = new C1TextRange(selection.End);
                Focus();
                // end of C1 library code ////////////////////////
            }
            e.Handled = true; // paste is done
        }
        else
        {
            // text is different -> something newer got copied from another control or application
            // -> let C1RichTextBox paste
        }
    }

    private bool TextsEqual(string t1, string t2)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(t2))
        {
            return false;
        }

        IEnumerable<char> chars1 = t1.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
        t1 = new string(chars1.ToArray());

        IEnumerable<char> chars2 = t2.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
        t2 = new string(chars2.ToArray());

        return t1 == t2;
    }

    private static string _clipboardText;
    private static string _clipboardHtml;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if you would have any suggestion for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55201990/1232087) also related to `ComponentOne`?