# convert RTF to HTML from ComponentOne RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, uwp, richtextbox, componentone

The section `Read and Write Rich Text Format Documents` of [this](https://www.grapecity.com/en/controls/uwp/richtextbox) online article of UWP edition of `ComponentOne` reads: `you can use it to convert RTF to HTML and vice versa.`

I went through their [API document](https://help.grapecity.com/componentone/NetHelp/C1worduwp/webframe.html#WordforUWPOverview.html) and did not find any code example of such functionality and could not figure out which method from their APIs to use.

**Question**: Could you please provide (or link to an online sample) for converting RTF to HTML from RichTextBox control of ComponentOne's UWP Edition? I'm using `C#` but `VB` code also be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ComponentOne` you can use it to convert RTF to HTML and vice versa.

You could convert between HTML and RTF using the [`RtfFilter`](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/FlexReport/C1.Win.C1Document.4~C1.Win.C1Document.Export.RtfFilter.html) library. And you could also get the code sample with this [link](https://www.grapecity.com/en/samples?platforms=uwp&search_term=richtextbox&display_limit=25).

```
rtfBox.Text = new RtfFilter().ConvertFromDocument(richTextBox.Document);
```

[image]